# Showing equality of scalar product of two vectors and the product of their lengths

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that the scalar product of two vectors, $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equal to the product of their lengths by the cosine of the angle they form.

**Background Info**:

Dot Product: two vectors, $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^2$:

$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+\dots + a_{n}b_{n}$$

Length of a Vector:

$$||\vec{a}||=\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}+\dots + a_{n}^{2}}$$

[image]
Recall the Law of Cosines: $c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\text{cos} \theta$

SO: $||c||^2=||a||^2 + ||b||^2 - 2||a||\cdot||a|| \text{cos} \theta$

Now consider:

$$||c||^2 = ||c||\cdot ||c||$$

$$= (a-b) \cdot (a-b)$$
$$= a^2 -a\cdot b -b\cdot a +b^2$$
$$=a^2 +b^2 -2a\cdot b$$

Notice that $$||a||^2 + ||b||^2 -2||a||\cdot ||b|| \text{cos} \theta = ||c||^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2a\cdot b$$.

I am stuck at this part since the goal of this proof is to show that

$$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = ||a|| \cdot ||b|| \text{cos} \theta$$
$$a_{1}b_{1}+\cdots + a_{n}b_{n} = ||a|| \cdot ||b|| \text{cos} \theta$$

Comment: The above shows that $2a \cdot b = \|a\| \|b\| \cos \theta$. (Or rather, an equation from which you can define $\cos \theta$.) Note that $a \cdot a = \|a\|^2$. As such, $a^2$ is meaningless.

Comment: im just having trouble with the proof. isnt the goal to show that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}=||a||\cdot ||b|| cos \theta$? How do i get the left to equal the right side? @copper.hat

Comment: You have two different expressions for $\|c\|^2$, when you equate them you get the above. However, note that this is really a definition of the value $\cos \theta$ that is consistent with the plane definition, rather than a proof that they are equal.

Comment: How would I go about the proof then

Comment: Proof of what? The above is tantamount to a definition of $\cos \theta$.

Comment: “Show that the scalar product of two vectors is equal to the product of the lengths of these vectors by the angle they form”

Comment: I may be missing something, but you have essentially done that (except you have stuff like $a^2$ where you should have $\|a\|^2$). Your equations result in the equality in my first comment.

Comment: Oohhh... cause since $2ab cos \theta = 2ab$ they cancel out and I am left with equality on the left side and the right side...correct?